# Virtual machine and VPN clients on same subnet

Tags: networking, virtualization

I have a Linux server running OpenVPN-AS and vmware player which runs a windows 2003 server.

I need the remote VPN clients to connect and access windows shares from the VM.

I can't figure out how to setup the network so this works properly.

I'm not sure if the VM should be in NAT or host-only mode and how to configure OpenVPN-AS. I've tried to configure both to be on the same network but I can't get it to go.

Thanks

Comment: Please tell me this is an off-topic question, and you're not virtualizing a Windows 2003 Server VM with VMware Player in a professional environment.  *<shudder>*

Comment: I am supporting a legacy application, I have no choice. I will be using KVM in production, not vmware. This was a physical server that I converted over. This is a temp solution until the new app is ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to set up OpenVPN on the Windows box as well so it is part of the VPN network, then in OpenVPN-AS allow all clients to see each other (I don't use OpenVPN-AS so I can't give exact details on this but it should be something like "Push LAN to clients" or whatnot).

Comment: I figured that would work, but I thought that it could be done by just putting the VM on the VPN network.

Comment: It could if you wanted to make things overly complicated but this is the easier and simplest solution.

Comment: This was my second choice but I tested it and it works fine. thanks